# Is there a way to see who authored old code in pycharm?

Tags: pycharm

In visual studio I can visit some ancient code in the codebase that hasn't been touched in years and it will tell me who authored it, how can I see this in pycharm without using git?

Comment: Neither PyCharm nor Visual Studio are version control systems, they are IDEs. Only a version control system like Git, SVN, etc could tell you that type of information.

Comment: PyCharm (and other JetBrains IDEs) have a version control system built-in (apart from git) but I'm not sure if it stores metadata like the author

Comment: @CoryKramer Yes I'm aware, but I have my github account linked to both VS and PyCharm and VS will show me author, was wondering if there was an option in pycharm to see this info.